# Upgrade Asp.net Project from 4 to 4.5 or 5

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I have Asp.net ,web Form project which is targeting 4.0 frame work. I need to use async c# concept but this version cannot pick that key word instead of it, its give me error async not define. I think it is versioning issue because async comes with 4.5. I also download packages from nuget package manager but its not picking async and give me error

> The type or namespace 'async' could not be found(are you missing
>   directives or missing references )

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Click on debug > YourProject Properties > Application

[image]

**Or**

Since async is feature of c# 5 read [here](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/mvpawardprogram/2012/03/26/an-introduction-to-new-features-in-c-5-0/)
 try update your [Visual studio](https://visualstudio.microsoft.com/) because some older version does not support c# 5